# Webview sometimes shows webpage not available

Tags: android, webview

On all of my apps I am getting a "webpage not available" error. This has just been happening recently, even on apps that have not been updated in awhile. At first I thought it was my server or domain name. However, everything loads on a mobile browser or desktop browser. The strangest part is that I can click on the link for the website given by the error and it works. Also, this isn't every time I get into the app. It sometimes load without any problems at all.

This is my main activity:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView mWebView;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Allow third party cookies for Android Lollipop
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebView,true);
    }

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);





    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && this.mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        this.mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You instantiated WebView twice that could be the reason.

```
cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebView,true);
```

You don't need this one below, you've done it already.

```
mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but it did not solve my problem. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Try this: enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw(false)

Comment: Tried that too and still no go. I did however noticed that when I go to my domain on a desktop it shows "Web page not found" for less than a second before it gets forwarded. I no longer believe this is a Webview error. I think this is a domain forwarding problem. Have any ideas for me?

Comment: I.will suggest you load it in Background thread e.g. AsynTask  and see how it goes?

Comment: I am not sure how to go about that, but I fixed my problem when I changed my domain from a forwarding one to one that points to an IP Address. Do you have any idea why that would be? To keep testing the problem, how would I got about using AsynTask?